# Dynamic JSON Creation in Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to dynamically create a JSON object in the following way. Note that the below code will not compile as I'm requesting your help on how to code it.

```
val favoriteFoods: JsArray = getArray() // gets Array of Array of JSON objects

val json: JsObject = Json.obj( 
   "name" : JsString("Kevin"),
   "FavoriteFood1" -> favoriteFoods.get(0), // note that I made up the get()
   "FavoriteFood2" -> favoriteFoods.get(1)
   )
```

Looking at the [JsArray](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsArray.html) docs, I didn't see any way to get the `i'th` element of a JsArray.

I tried to add an if statement to check if a new `FavoriteFood` could be added, but it would not compile.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? And why wouldn't you use a pre-existing function to do this like `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the version of Play Framework you're using.  I'm familiar with 1.X, so this answer is from that perspective.  Play provides a renderJSON() method.   Here's the docs:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/controllers

Scroll down to the section that reads 'Return a JSON String'